# Where can I get cheap medicine?

Tags: pokemon-diamond-pearl-platinum

I am playing Pokémon Pearl and I want to know where to find cheap medicine. I want to know where to buy items such as Moomoo Milk and Lemonade that cost less than normal potions and Herbal medicines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nowhere you can get "cheap" medicine. The prices you see are the prices you get. However, if you're looking for the most cost effective items for healing, the [Fresh Water](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Drink#Fresh_Water) (heals for 50) and [Energy Root](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Herbal_medicine#Energy_Root) (heals for 200) offer the most bang for your buck. Fresh Water is found at the [Veilstone Department Store](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Veilstone_Department_Store) top floor, and Energy Root is found at the [Herb Shop](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Herb_Shop) in Eterna City.

Comment: Do you know where to find Moomoo milk?

Comment: @Oreo Cafe Cabin on Route 210, according to Wiki page.

Comment: Note that Energy Root will lower your Pokémon's [friendship](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Friendship), so if the Pokémon knows Return or evolves through friendship (e.g., Eevee -> Espeon), you should probably avoid using bitter herbs.